# Google Map V2 in Tab Group Activity

Tags: android

Tabhost with Google map android api v2 is showing google map in fragmentActivity using tabhost, but can't able to access the controls..The view placed in tabgroup activity is not replaced.

Comment: Can you post some code here?

Comment: and the question is ?